# Get the value of one array according to another arrays index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the value of the numierical value inside array1 by using the index of array2. So for instance my arrays look like this:

```
const array1 = ["3","4","5","6","7","8"];
const array2 = ["bat","cat","dog","fish","cow","bird"];
```

If the user selects `"cat"`, it should grab `"4"`.

```
array2.forEach(animal => {
   console.log(array1.indexOf(animal)); // returns -1 
});
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the current index of `array2` into the `forEach` callback (second argument)

```js
const array1 = ["3","4","5","6","7","8"];
const array2 = ["bat","cat","dog","fish","cow","bird"];

array2.forEach((animal, i) => {
   console.log(array1[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use bracket notation and `indexOf`

```js
const array1 = ["3","4","5","6","7","8"];
const array2 = ["bat","cat","dog","fish","cow","bird"];

let choice = 'cat'; // user selection

let result = array1[array2.indexOf(choice)]; // grab value

alert(result);
```

Comment: Nice. I completely missed the context of the "user choice", and simply was looking at the loop issue. +1

Comment: You shouldn´t use let since the question doesn´t give information enough to determine the function or the scope, use var instead in code examples unless you have enough information :) still +1 for a nice catch on the problem

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari - the OP is using `const`, so let's assume he knows the difference between `let`, `var` and `const`.

Comment: Never assume anything, that is the first thing that leads to bugs ;)

Comment: If I didn't assume, I could never post an answer to anything on here? The OP is using `const` which has the same scoping as `let`, so I don't see the problem, the OP can change the declaration to whatever may fit.

Comment: Most people that ask questions have googled their code, not quite knowing how to do a thing, which is the reason to them posting here, so assuming a lot might be misinterpreted is a way of staying clear that the code might be prone to mistakes. You can assume, but don´t give answers due to the presumptions. Oh well, interesting discussion, but I think we should leave it at that, I 1+´ed your answer anyway, nice catch

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari - sure, no problem, thanks for the input, but I still don't see an issue with using `let` just because it's block scoped, and could be used wrongly by some users.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the problem would be that others that find this question might have a hard time with finding the solution, since the neither the scope or function is shown in the question, so if it is a function variable, the question and answer will just lure them further away from the answer if they don´t understand the difference of var and let and scope and function. I hope I´m not sounding too confusing. I found it to be the biggest problem for myself to find the right answers when I was a junior. Answers should be kept to their absolute :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some change.

There are two conditions as I understood. The first one is you get the animal name and search for the related index in array1. Second one is that you do a loop on array2 and you get related items in array1.

```
//First condition
var animalName = 'XXX'; // You get this from the user.
var indexOfAnimal = array2.indexOf(animalName); 
var relatedItem = array1[indexOfAnimal];

//Second condition
foreach(var index in array2){
    console.log(array1[index]);
}

//Your code with changes
array2.forEach(animal => {
    var indexOfAnimal = array2.indexOf(animal);
    console.log(array1[indexOfAnimal]);
});
```